# Given an .ipa how can it be determined if its a debug or release build?

Tags: ios

The question is - if I have a .ipa, how can it be determined if it is a debug build or a release build?

[This question has been asked a couple of times before, but the answers provided DO NOT answer the actual question, the answers instead talk about things such as how to create a debug or release build etc.].

Answer (score -1):

You can upload .ipa file to https://www.diawi.com/.
If you can install it on your phone, it is the release version.

Comment: But can't you also upload a dev build to diwali and install that too?